# LEFT JOIN for three MySQL tables and NOT

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL database I have three connected tables: **texts** links to **editions**, which links to the intermediary table **editor_attestations** (I think the fourth table editors is not relevant here). Often each text has multiple editions, and in turn each edition often has several editor_attestations (through joint publication).

If I want to get all texts and editions with a specific editor, this works fine:

```
SELECT texts.text_id FROM texts
LEFT JOIN editions ON texts.text_id = editions.text_id
LEFT JOIN editor_attestations ON editions.edition_id = editor_attestations.edition_id
WHERE editor_attestations.editor_id = 102
```

Now I have tried several things get all texts NOT edited by editor_id = 102, but none seems to work.

```
SELECT texts.text_id FROM texts
LEFT JOIN editions ON texts.text_id = editions.text_id
LEFT JOIN editor_attestations ON editions.edition_id = editor_attestations.edition_id
WHERE (editor_attestations.editor_id != 102 or editor_attestations.editor_id is null)
```

has many records in the result where editor_id 102 has cooperated with someone else, so that editor_attestations.editor_id != 102 holds true. But I want to exclude those.

I want to include only values in table 1 (texts) which are NOT in any way connected with a specific value in table 3 (editor_attestations).

I have tried with NOT IN or NOT EXISTS with subqueries, but that does not work.

I have the feeling it should not be so complicated ...

Comment: "I have tried with NOT IN or NOT EXISTS with subqueries" - Please post your attempt with NOT EXISTS. Maybe you just need a little fix.

Comment: I had the following: WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM editor_attestations WHERE texts.text_id = editions.text_id AND editions.edition_id = editor_attestations.edition_id AND editor_attestation.editor_id = 102), with a similar problem as below.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want only the `texts.text_id`s, you can group by `texts.text_id` and set the condition in the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT texts.text_id 
FROM texts
LEFT JOIN editions ON texts.text_id = editions.text_id
LEFT JOIN editor_attestations ON editions.edition_id = editor_attestations.edition_id
GROUP BY texts.text_id 
HAVING SUM(editor_attestations.editor_id = 102) = 0
```

Comment: This works indeed, but the problem is that I need more from the query than just the texts. I want the number of texts and the number of editions. In fact I extracted COUNT(DISTINCT(texts.text_id)) as number_texts, COUNT(DISTINCT(editions.edition_id)) as number_editions.

Comment: Then why didn't you mention this requirement in the question? All the answers you get propose solutions for what you asked.

Comment: I guess I did not want to complicate it further, but I should probably have, sorry.

Comment: *I did not want to complicate it further* so you post a simplified question and you get simplified answers.

Answer (score 1):

The answers from forpas and xavier demonstrate workable approaches.

As a demonstration of an approach using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT t.text_id 
  FROM texts t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                      FROM editions e
                      JOIN editor_attestations a 
                        ON a.edition_id = e.edition_id
                     WHERE a.editor_id = 102 
                       AND e.text_id = t.text_id
                  )
```

Note the predicate in the subquery `e.text_id = t.text_id` that correlates the subquery to the outer query.

This approach allows additional columns from `texts` to be returned, without duplicating rows that might otherwise occur using a JOIN operation.

For large sets, suitable indexes are needed for optimal performance.

---

Another alternative is to use an anti-join pattern:

```
 SELECT t.text_id 
   FROM texts t
     -- match to editor_id=102
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT e.text_id 
            FROM editions e
            JOIN editor_attestations a
              ON a.edition_id = e.edition_id
           WHERE a.editor_id = 102
           GROUP BY e.text_id
        ) s
     ON s.text_id = t.text_id
     -- exclude rows that had a match
  WHERE s.text_id IS NULL
```

The inline view query `s` gets us a distinct list of `text_id` which are related to `editor_id=102`.  The antijoin is a left outer join to the return from this query, so it returns all rows texts, along with matching rows from `s`. The trick is a condition in the WHERE clause that excludes rows that had a match (if there was a matching row from `s`, we are guaranteed that `s.text_id` will be non-null, since only non-null values can satisfy the equality comparison in the join condition (`ON s.text_id =`).  If we exclude those rows, we are left with rows from `texts` that do *not* have any matching row from `s`.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy solution would be: I look for all the texts that have been modified by a certain editor and I take the complementary set. It might not be very efficient but for a small database it will work:

```
SELECT texts.text_id FROM texts where texts.text_id NOT IN
  (SELECT editions.text_id FROM editions
    JOIN editor_attestations ON editions.edition_id = editor_attestations.edition_id
    WHERE editor_attestations.editor_id = 102
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried this. Although the tables contain several hundred thousands records each, performance does not seem to be the problem. I get the same result as I have had in other experiments with NOT IN: the results include all editions of texts which have another edition that does not point to editor 102. I clarify: text 2 has an edition that does not point to editor 102, and all its editions appear in the results list.

Comment: You should provide some data to test it, but with this query you shouldn't get any text that has been edited by 102.

Comment: That should be INNER JOINs in the subquery. And you don't need `texts` in the subquery. You can select `text_id` from `editions` table.

Comment: note that with the WHERE clause requiring a non-null value, that negates the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN, rendering them equivalent to a plain old inner join. As an aid to the future reader, we could avoid some obfuscation by omitting the unnecessary `LEFT` keywords. We should also note that we need to have some guarantee that `texts.text_id` is non-NULL, i.e. that the subquery won't ever return a NULL value.

Comment: You're right. I deleted the LEFTs. Thank you for your comments

Comment: I removed the `editions` table to make it simpler. The original answer tried to show I was just taking the complementary set: I take the whole set and I subtract all the elements of the original query. Simple. But you are right this way is better